# @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars raises a warn where it shouldn't

Tags: typescript, webpack, eslint

I'm trying to start a project with webpack, typescript and eslint. And I'm getting a warn `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` here:
[image]

I can't achive `argv` value without achiving `env`. Is the only way to avoid the error in this case - is to simulate the use of variable `env`?

My **eslint.json**:

```json
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es2020": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true,
            "modules": true,
            "arrowFunctions": true,
            "classes": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 11,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint",
        "import"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-console": ["error", {
            "allow": ["timeEnd", "warn"]
        }],
        "func-names": "off",
        "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"],
        "no-plusplus": "off",
        "max-len": ["error", {"code":  120}],
        "indent": ["error", 4, {
            "ignoredNodes": ["JSXElement *"]
        }],
        "arrow-parens": ["error", "as-needed"],
        "import/order": ["error", {
            "pathGroups": [{
                "pattern": "@*/**",
                "group": "parent",
                "position": "before"
            }],
            "groups": ["builtin", "external", "internal", "parent", "sibling", "index"],
            "alphabetize": {"order": "asc"}
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a regex for this eslint rule to indicate known unused function arguments with the property `argsIgnorePattern`. One common regex is `"argsIgnorePattern": "^_"` to ignore all variable starting with an underscore. With this configuration, you can write:

```js
module.exports = (_: {} = {}, argv: {} = {}) => {
```

For information, here is my configuration:

```yaml
  '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars':
    - error
    - argsIgnorePattern: '^_'
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't help

Comment: What do you need more? Can't you modify eslint configuration?

Comment: I did modify my configuration, but the warning didn't gone

Comment: My bad, this is not `varsIgnorePattern` but `argsIgnorePattern` for function arguments. I updated the answer.